# Inject headers into httptest.Recorder so echo context can see them in Golang

Tags: http, go, go-echo

I have some tests that inject headers into Echo like this:

```
func test() {
    request := httptest.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "/", http.NoBody)
    recorder := httptest.NewRecorder()
    recorder.HeaderMap.Add("If-None-Match", "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"")

    context := inst.NewContext(request, recorder)

    testFunc(context)

    fmt.Printf("Status: %d", context.Response().Status)
}

func testFunc(ctx echo.Context) {
    ifNoneMatch := ctx.Response().Header().Get(headers.IfNoneMatch)
    if !util.IsEmpty(ifNoneMatch) && etag == ifNoneMatch {
        ctx.Response().WriteHeader(304)
    }
}
```

My current solution works but, as `HeaderMap` is deprecated, I'm trying to find a better way to do this. I've tried injecting the header into `Result` by doing `Result().Header.Add("If-None-Match", "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"")` but it doesn't seem to show up when calling `context.Response().Header()`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Deprecated: HeaderMap exists for historical compatibility and should not be used. To access the headers returned by a handler, use the Response.Header map as returned by the Result method.` so `recorder.Result().Request.Header.Set("1", "2")`

Comment: @AlexEfimov That doesn't work though

Comment: but why would you want to add headers to recorder and not request? The function that processes the request should add the header to the response (recorder).

Comment: @AlexEfimov I agree but for some reason my test doesn't work if I add the headers the way you specified. `test` should print a 304 for the status code but I'm getting a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using HeaderMap() which is deprecated, you can use this:

```
request.Header().Set("Header-name", "Any header")
```